# dynamic content on static site generators

Tags: content-management-system, gatsby, strapi

If you have a headless CMS combined with a SSG, what is the best way to push changes to your site? Do you listen for a change event and regenerate the whole site and redeploy each time? Or do you run the SSG on some timed interval?

I'm currently learning Gatsby(SSG) and Strapi(headless CMS), and I know Netlify offer services that combine SSG and a CMS for you. And Netlify does up to 3 builds per minute for free.

What is the best approach for pushing dynamic content to a SSG?

Answer (score 2):

Both approaches would work. The first is known as webhooks and there is a planned plugin that you can vote for at https://strapi.io/vote

The latter is likely less efficient and can be achieved with a cron job, for now this is the option I think.